# When did LEGO start adding a progress-bar to build instructions?

Tags: instructions

Set [#40549](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/demogorgon-eleven-40549) has a stud moving along a progress bar at the bottom of each pair of pages, as you move through the instructions. The stud moves left to right.

[image]

I've never seen this in any other instruction booklet.

1. Why does this set have it?
2. Are there other sets which have it?
3. If it's a new feature for all sets, when was it added?

Comment: I have e-mailed LEGO support, to see if they can enlighten us.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've had an answer from LEGO customer service. They only advised one other set which includes the progress bar, which is "Star Wars Hoth AT-ST (75322)". They did however mention "a select few", so there may well be more. I've asked if there's a complete list of released sets that have the progress bar.

It has been added in 2022.

**Update 12th February 2023**

Harry Potter set 76406 (Hungarian Horntail) has a Harry minifig progress bar.

Harry Potter set 76403 (Ministry of Magic) has a Mafalda Hopkirk/Hermione Granger minifig progress bar.

Comment: It's also in the 2022 "The Mandalorian's N-1 Starfighter™" 75325 manual, with a Mandalorian minifigure instead of a stud.